# sql : how to delete all rows of certain columns?

Tags: sql

Suppose that I have such table :

[image]

and I would like to delete all the rows of columns `score` `year` and `month`, without modifying `id` and `name`.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: update them to be blank for those values

Comment: Do you want to keep the columns in the table with null values, or are you trying to remove them from the table completely?

Comment: If you delete a row, the row is gone and so is the id and name. Or do you mean that you want to remove those columns entirely, or do you just want to delete all values of those columns, but retain the columns?

Comment: Hi guys! So I want to keep all the columns, just want to delete the values of those columns (or change them to Null)

Comment: Update .. set col = null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for an `UPDATE`, not a `DELETE`. `DELETE` only operates on full rows.

So:

```
UPDATE table
SET 
  score = NULL,
  year = NULL,
  month = NULL;
```

You usually want a `WHERE` clause on an `UPDATE`, but if you want to wipe out all the current data in those columns, you don't need one here.

Since it's numeric data, you could set them all to `0` instead of `NULL`, depending on your preferences and needs, and also the nullability setting for each column. Anything defined with `NOT NULL` at table creation will have to be updated to an acceptable value, like a `0` for an integer.

Comment: What if it's a date ? is it possible to set to Null?

Comment: @ayay If the value is a nullable, it's possible to set almost anything to null